# I am trying to make an array and i want a hint for my smallest number because i feel like it is not the right way to do it

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to do an assignment for the school so please just give me some hints and not the answer.
Take a look at this array program, Everything is working but I need to find the smallest number in the array and I feel what I have done is not the most efficient way.
Can anyone help:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    double sum=0.0;
    double average=0.0;
    double big=0.0;
    double small=10000000000000;


    std::cout<<"Please enter 5 numbers\n";
    double nums[5];


    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Input a number into your array:";
        std::cin>> nums[i];
        sum+=nums[i];
        average=(sum/5);
    }

    for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
    {
        std::cout<<nums[x]<<std::endl;

        if(big<nums[x])
        {
          big=nums[x];
        }

        if(small>nums[x])
        {
            small=nums[x];
        }
    }

    std::cout<<"The sum of all the values is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The average of all the values is: "<<average<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The largest value is :"<< big<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The smallest value is :"<< small<<std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `std::numeric_limits`. For the record, properly formatting code makes it so much easier to read

Comment: Since you have at least one element, you can start with assuming that the first element is both smallest and largest.

Comment: Why are you repeatedly overwriting `average` in your loop? Other than initializing `small` and `big` to the first number and looping from the second number, there is not much that you can do to make it faster.

Comment: Please remove "I am, I feel, I want"... i really do not want to read about "I" in question titles.. its soooo selfish and sad. More like.. what is it about and the problem itself as topic. Cheers.

Comment: @ZF007: That's called "therapeutic language" and is intertwined with "taking responsibility" (the mock one). So say hello to the counterproductive crap the millennial generation has been fed (up) with.

Comment: @zx485 ... so true unfortunately. We call them here "display" generation.. They should be tatood with "(MS)DOS... was here..."